# Fréchet Derivative of a functional appearing in variational calculus

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I would like to compute the Fréchet derivative of the functional

$$ J: C^1[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$$
$$y \mapsto \int_a^b L(x,y(x),y'(x)) \, dx $$

where $L$ is $C^2$ in all components.

The Fréchet derivative of $J$ in a point $y$ is defined to be the bounded linear operator $A_y$ such that
$$\lim_{||h||_{C^1([a,b])} \rightarrow 0} \frac{|J(y+h) -J(y) -A_yh|}{||h||_{C^1([a,b])}}=0$$

In my book, it says it is easily computable by Taylor expansions, but I really do not see how. They just go from there to Euler-Lagrange equation immediately. Online, I saw many convincing heuristics but no rigorous proof using the definition of the Fréchet derivative.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Henri Cartan's book: Differential Forms. There, he has an entire chapter devoted to variational calculus formulated in the context of Banach spaces. Also, take a look at Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced calculus; there is a short section (3.15) on Calculus of Variations

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier way to find out the value for $A_y$.

Fix $h\in C^1[a,b]$ and calculate the limit
$$
\lim_{t\to0} \frac1t (J(y+th)-J(y)).
$$
The result gives you the value for $A_y h$.
From that you obtain the (bounded linear) operator $A_y$.

However, you still need to verify that
$$\lim_{||h||_{C^1([a,b])} \rightarrow 0} \frac{|J(y+h) -J(y) -A_yh|}{||h||_{C^1([a,b])}}=0$$
holds in order to show that $A_y$ is a Fréchet derivative.
But this is now easier because you know the operator $A_y$ and do not have to guess.

Comment: It is exactly that second part that I cannot do and that utilize Taylor expansion. I know Euler-Lagrange equation, so I know what $A_y$ is supposed to be. But in most things I read online, they do not prove that it is indeed the Fréchet derivative.

Comment: @W.Volante Then you really should have included that information in your question. Also, you could add an attempt of your own, and maybe use the hint for Taylor expansions.